# Replacing Parts of a String C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a series of strings that look like "WORD1: JUNK1 WORD2: JUNK2" and I want to remove the junk from the string while preserving the number of characters between the words (including those taken up by the junk).

- I have a list of what words will be used but not junk
- The words, number of spaces between everything, and junk all change every line

So far I've been using a regex like `(word|word|word)(.\*)(word|word|word)(.*)` but I don't know how to maintain the formatting that way.

**EDITED**

Sorry, you were right, WORD1/WORD2 and JUNK1/JUNK2 are meant to be variables for the actual values I've been seeing. Its all alphanumeric characters and slashes.

**Input Examples:**

"CATEGORY:(4 spaces)SIDES(3 spaces)DATE CREATED:(3 spaces)03/12/16"

"PRODUCT:(6 spaces)CARROTS(4 spaces)DATE DELETED:(4 spaces)05/11/17"

**Output Examples:**

"CATEGORY:(12 spaces)DATE CREATED:(11 spaces)"

"PRODUCT:(17 spaces)DATE DELETED:(12 spaces"

I am trying to replace the word "SIDES" as well as "03/12/16" with spaces. Rather, I want the number of characters between CATEGORY and DATE CREATED to remain the same and all be spaces.

Comment: The things you are after, is it always a single word (`A-Za-z`) with a colon after?

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include a full input and expected output?

Comment: Might it be easier to just split it up into words - replace the ones you don't want and then join them up again?

Comment: If you could post some before (input) and after (expected output), it would make your question a bit easier to understand. Did you mean **input:** `WORD1: JUNK1 WORD2: JUNK2"` **output:** `WORD1: _____ WORD2: _____` ?

Comment: Is `JUNK` ever going to have a `:` in it?  You could just split on space and take only the elements that contain a `:`

Comment: If I'm understanding this right, you want to find where it says 'JUNK', and replace it with 4 empty spaces, or some other character? Can't `String.Replace()` work for you?

Comment: @Frontear I think its safe to say Split would not work considering the OP's example says `JUNK1` and `JUNK2` meaning that the "junk" is not a constant

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but won't String.Replace("JUNK", ...); still be able to find JUNK1, it just wouldn't replace the '1'. Does OP want the '1' removed as well?

Comment: I think 'JUNK' is a dynamic/unknown Word (if I understand correctly).

Comment: Try `Regex.Replace(s, @"(\G(?!^)\s*|\b(?:CATEGORY|PRODUCT|DATE (?:CREA|DELE)TED):\s*)(?!\b(?:CATEGORY|PRODUCT|DATE (?:CREA|DELE)TED):)\S", " ")`, see [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cG%28%3f!%5e%29%5cs*%7c%5cb%28%3f%3aCATEGORY%7cPRODUCT%7cDATE+%28%3f%3aCREA%7cDELE%29TED%29%3a%5cs*%29%28%3f!%5cb%28%3f%3aCATEGORY%7cPRODUCT%7cDATE+%28%3f%3aCREA%7cDELE%29TED%29%3a%29%5cS&i=CATEGORY%3a++++SIDES+++DATE+CREATED%3a+++03%2f12%2f16%0d%0aPRODUCT%3a++++++CARROTS++++DATE+DELETED%3a++++05%2f11%2f17&r=%241+&o=m).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Please read this link, understand it, and post another question about your ACTUAL problem...

Comment: @dognose, I'm normally the first guy thinking someone has an X/Y problem, but I don't see any indication here. This could have a use case of redaction among many other uses. The initial question needed work, but after the updates I think it's a very interesting issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a solution that is based on a `Regex.Split` operation:

```
var s = "CATEGORY:    SIDES   DATE CREATED:   03/12/16";
var rx = @"(\b(?:CATEGORY|PRODUCT|DATE (?:CREA|DELE)TED):)";
var chunks = Regex.Split(s, rx);
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(
    chunks.Select(
        x => Regex.IsMatch(x, $"^{rx}$") ? x : new String(' ', x.Length))
    )
);
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/4hIwx3)

The `(\b(?:CATEGORY|PRODUCT|DATE (?:CREA|DELE)TED):)` regex is the delimiter pattern inside a capturing group so that `Regex.Split` could add the matches to the resulting array. It matches whole words `CATEGORY`, `PRODUCT`, `DATE CREATED` and `DATE DELETED`, and then a `:`. If the item matches this delimiter fully (see `^` and `$` anchors in `Regex.IsMatch(x, $"^{rx}$")`) then it must stay as is, else, a string of spaces is built `new String(' ', x.Length)`.

If you need a purely regex solution, you may use

```
var delim = @"\b(?:CATEGORY|PRODUCT|DATE (?:CREA|DELE)TED):";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, $@"(\G(?!^)\s*|{delim}\s*)(?!{delim})\S", "$1 "));
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5CG%28%3F!%5E%29%5Cs*%7C%5Cb%28%3F%3ACATEGORY%7CPRODUCT%7CDATE%20%28%3F%3ACREA%7CDELE%29TED%29%3A%5Cs*%29%28%3F!%5Cb%28%3F%3ACATEGORY%7CPRODUCT%7CDATE%20%28%3F%3ACREA%7CDELE%29TED%29%3A%29%5CS&i=CATEGORY%3A%20%20%20%20SIDES%20%20%20DATE%20CREATED%3A%20%20%2003%2F12%2F16%0D%0APRODUCT%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20CARROTS%20%20%20%20DATE%20DELETED%3A%20%20%20%2005%2F11%2F17&r=%241%20&o=m).

**Details**

- `(\G(?!^)\s*|{delim}\s*)` - Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern): the end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`) followed with 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`) or (`|`) the `delim` pattern with 0+ whitespaces
- `(?!{delim})\S` - any non-whitespace char that is not a starting char of a `delim` sequence

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone will give you a nice clean answer using regex but here's a quick solution off the top of my head:

```
string msg = "this is a silly test message";
string[] junk = new string[] { "silly", "message" };

foreach(string j in junk)
{
    msg = Regex.Replace(msg, j, string.Empty.PadRight(j.Length));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was an interesting experiment and I came up with what appears to be a very different method than the other answers.

```
public class WordStripper
{
    public string StripWords(string input)
    {
        var ignoreWords = new List<string>
        {
            "CATEGORY:",
            "DATE CREATED:",
            "PRODUCT:",
            "DATE DELETED:"
        };
        var deliminator = string.Join("|", ignoreWords);
        var splitInput = Regex.Split(input, $"({deliminator})");
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var word in splitInput)
        {
            if (ignoreWords.Contains(word))
            {
                sb.Append(word);
            }
            else
            {
                var wordLength = word.Length;
                sb.Append(new string(' ', wordLength));
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

And a unit test to validate it in case you're interested (uses NUnit)

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    [TestCase("CATEGORY:    SIDES   DATE CREATED:   03/12/16", "CATEGORY:            DATE CREATED:           ")]
    [TestCase("PRODUCT:      CARROTS    DATE DELETED:    05/11/17", "PRODUCT:                 DATE DELETED:            ")]
    public void TestMethod(string input, string expectedResult)
    {
        //arrange
        var uut = new WordStripper();

        //act
        var actualResults = uut.StripWords(input);

        //assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResults);
    }
}
```